# "startsWith" method

Tags: java, webview

It's showing unknown method "startsWith"
If it's the incorrect way then please tell the correct way

```
EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);

WebView webv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.b);

if (editTxt.startsWith("http://"){
    webv.loadUrl(editTxt.getText().toString());
}else{
    webv.loadUrl("http://" + editTxt.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) is method of `String`, you need to convert to String first:

```
String editTxtString = editTxt.getText().toString();
if (editTxtString .startsWith("http://")) {
    webv.loadUrl(editTxtString);
} else {
    webv.loadUrl("http://" + editTxtString);
}
```

Or one liner:

```
webv.loadUrl(editTxtString .startsWith("http://")? editTxtString: "http://" + editTxtString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is editText is string class? You post to little code but try thisif editText is not String class:

```
if (editTxt.getText().toString().startsWith("http://"){
    webv.loadUrl(editTxt.getText().toString());
}else{
    webv.loadUrl("http://" + editTxt.getText().toString());
}
```